# TS generics and derived types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to create a function that takes care of calling some other functions. These other functions should trigger similar business and cleanup logic.

```js
function foo(arg: number) {
    // do something with arg
}

function bar(arg: string) {
    // do something with arg
}

const FUNCTIONS = {
    foo,
    bar,
} as const;

type FnType = keyof typeof FUNCTIONS;

type FnArg<Type extends FnType> = Parameters<typeof FUNCTIONS[Type]>[0];

function callFunction<Type extends FnType>(type: Type, arg: FnArg<Type>) {
    // some business logic here that is shared by all functions

    const fn = FUNCTIONS[type];

    // the type of fn and arg are both derived from Type:
    // - 'typeof fn' would be 'typeof Functions[Type]'
    // - 'typeof args' would be 'FnArg<Type>'
    // However, TS seems to see these 2 types as independent and cannot
    // figure out that fn and arg can work together.

    return fn(arg); // -> TS doesn't 'know' that arg should have the right type although we know that's the case thanks to generics
}

// generics make sure the second argument is of the right type
callFunction('foo', 5);
callFunction('foo', 'arg'); // errors as expected

callFunction('bar', 'arg');
callFunction('bar', 5); // erros as expected
```

I'm able to use generics to make sure TS checks that the arguments that will be proxied to these functions are of the right type. However, within the function implementation, TS does not seem to know that the generics will make sure the argument is of the right type.

Do you know if there is a way to make TS understand that calling `fn(arg)` will be fine?

Comment: It's always difficult to deal with unions of function types. :-| How many different kinds of functions do you have in `FUNCTIONS`? We may be able to give you an alternative to your current generics approach.

Comment: (Alternatively, sadly there are times within the implementation of a generic function where type assertions are needed.)

Comment: We've got 3 functions at the moment, but there could be more in the future, what alternative did you have in mind?

Comment: This is essentially [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended fix is a refactor to generic indexed accesses into mapped types as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXvE8m) for that technique applied to this example. Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Interestingly, something **very** like this [came up here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76091522/typescript-how-can-i-describe-an-object-key-dynamically-with-generics) as well. I think it's the same answer.

Comment: Yep, that does the trick @jcalz! Could you post it as an answer (instead of a comment) as I can't mark it as the answer otherwise.

Comment: Sure, that's why I offered to write up an answer if it addresses your question.  I'll do it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you saw, the compiler cannot see the correlation between the type of `FUNCTIONS[type]` and the type of `arg`.  The issue is essentially the same as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), where it's phrased in terms of correlated [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  Unless you're very careful, when the compiler tries to call `FUNCTIONS[type](arg)`, it will widen the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type of `FUNCTIONS[type]` to the union `((arg: string) => void) | (arg: number) => void))`, and the type of `arg` to `string | number`, and unfortunately you cannot call the former with an argument of the latter.  Indeed the compiler collapses the union of functions to the single function of an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of its parameters (as described in [the release notes for TS3.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)) and you get `(arg: never) => void`, which cannot be called at all, since it requires an argument of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type); something can't be both a `string` and a `number`.  So if you do it this way, you're stuck:

```
function callFunction<K extends keyof FnArg>(type: K, arg: FnArg[K]) {
  const fn = FUNCTIONS[type];
  // const fn: (arg: never) => void
  // (parameter) arg: string | number
  return fn(arg); // error! 
}
```

---

Luckily there is a way to fix it, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The idea is to refactor your types so that they are explicitly written as operations on generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over a simple or "base" object type.  The point is that you want `fn` to be seen as having the generic type `(arg: XXX) => void` and you want `arg` to be seen as type `XXX` for the same generic `XXX`.  So the type of `FUNCTIONS` has to be changed to map over that base type.

Here's one way to do it.  First we rename your `FUNCTIONS` variable out of the way:

```
const _FUNCTIONS = {
  foo,
  bar,
} as const;
```

Then we use it to construct that base object type:

```
type FnArg = { [K in keyof typeof _FUNCTIONS]:
  Parameters<typeof _FUNCTIONS[K]>[0] }

/* type FnArg = {
    readonly foo: number;
    readonly bar: string;
} */
```

And then we declare `FUNCTIONS` to be a mapped type over `FnArg`:

```
const FUNCTIONS: {
  [K in keyof FnArg]: (arg: FnArg[K]) => void
} = _FUNCTIONS;
```

And now you can write `callFunction()` as operating on generic indexed accesses:

```
function callFunction<K extends keyof FnArg>(type: K, arg: FnArg[K]) {
  const fn = FUNCTIONS[type];
  // const fn: (arg: FnArg[K]) => void
  // (parameter) arg: FnArg[K]
  return fn(arg); // okay
}
```

There you go!

---

Note that the type of `FUNCTIONS` and the type of `_FUNCTIONS` are equivalent, especially if you ask IntelliSense to display them:

```
/* const _FUNCTIONS: {
    readonly foo: (arg: number) => void;
    readonly bar: (arg: string) => void;
} */

/* const FUNCTIONS: {
    readonly foo: (arg: number) => void;
    readonly bar: (arg: string) => void;
} */
```

The only difference between them is how they are internally represented, and the mapped type `FUNCTIONS` type allows the compiler to see the correlation betwen `FUNCTIONS[type]` and `arg`.  If you replace `FUNCTIONS` with `_FUNCTIONS` inside the body of `callFuction()`, your original error will come right back.

The issue is therefore a subtle one, and all I can do here is to point people to microsoft/TypeScript#47109 for a source for this technique, where the implementer explains how and why it works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDATgcwFyJggC2ARgKZYCUiA3ogL4BQoksCip2muBAzlCwwwOGvWZMICAYgD6AMQCqAOQDCAFQCSAeWUBlRAF46TRMlQAaU52xWGiDH0RSwAgNxMA9ACpn0qHJKalq6egS01mZY5BgAJggANgCe5nAEPPiEJBTURgB8iABucDCxHmZRMfFgyTZY6diZAkIiNIYFxaUe9t6eTExQSQAO5IjyYACCuEZ0iADaANKIwogA1uRJcMCIgyNbgSoaOvoAunjWAArYGMTkUJR8ADy75PsKhyH6iyd5cwAMJ0Y-R8O2Go3GUxwMwiFUQ0TiiRSKDSWTIlHKFXh1VqXHqiGawhw3UQvX6LhkQSOoXC1kWyyQ6022whuDOiAyBBZOG+bQ6JViTHsxnewWOeg8IPJAUpnzCJlhWMRqQavFROV5RX5GMqCJqKVxKqagkJGs6ZUFJL6LHA0HgSAgGASCXkNvYYEeS3IAA97mBYk5GfsuXk0C8CAsLA5VVyefK-K4AsAkMYZWK5i8ThjPJ54zIk4bOZNcLH2prStZs+yhtdbvdco1C5DvtZolAQFgkEmMlRuv1WLaOA6nXo4i62HaPYhvb7-WsNkGizgQ2HEBGo5kYwsTmJrFLkMmDqLQumwZmKzm9-n2Q3CORCpRTfzz1Wa3cH+v+MaRIgAD5qygtnc7admA3a9mSjrOq6dpoAA5MisGRgArD2kiQWOA6gfBqCIYgsGNLBPaIJWlBYHAWBOI4U5eiM0DkAKaFOhhbpwbiuH4bghEeEOUHjggrHYLhKFuMROakXAlFON6tH3AKQA)