# Typescript: How can I describe an object key dynamically with generics?

Tags: javascript, typescript, event-handling, typescript-generics

I am trying to describe a dictionary of event handlers (with different payload shapes) like this:

```js
type Events = 'foo' | 'bar';

type EventsPayload = { foo: string, bar: number };
type EventHandler<Event extends Events> = (args: EventsPayload[Event]) => void;

const eventHandlers: { [Event in Events]?: EventHandler<Event> } = {};
export function addEventHandler<Event extends Events>(
  name: Event,
  handler: EventHandler<Event>,
) {
  eventHandlers[name] = handler;
}
```

This is giving me the error:

> Type 'EventHandler' is not assignable to type '{ foo?: EventHandler<"foo"> | undefined; bar?: EventHandler<"bar"> | undefined; }[Event]'.

If I remove the generics when I insert the handler method it works:

```js
eventHandlers.foo = (payload: string) => {};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it work by referring to the type of `eventHandlers` when defining the type of the `handler` parameter. (This is what they do for `addEventListener` in `lib.dom.d.ts`, for example.) I find it easiest to do that by using a type alias for the type of the `eventHandlers` object:

```typescript
type Events = "foo" | "bar";

type EventsPayload = { foo: string; bar: number };
type EventHandler<Event extends Events> = (args: EventsPayload[Event]) => void;

// *** Define the type
type EventHandlers = {
    [Event in Events]?: EventHandler<Event>;
};

const eventHandlers: EventHandlers = {};

// *** Use it for `handler`
export function addEventHandler<Event extends Events>(
    name: Event,
    handler: EventHandlers[Event]
) {
    eventHandlers[name] = handler;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAzlAvFARAMwPZ5ZQA+2ARgIYBOWA3ALABQToksCyKAChSADZ4KAEwxQA3lHx4AXFBTAqAS0QBzWlEpVZiAK4BbMhCpQAvg0ato8JMAASFREL5GAPNeRQIAD2BIhad1QAPlEACmoVFFlA7l4BYQBtQIBdAEoMELg8RSFzJgB6fKgAKlKoABEIHGVoYAALWvAIFib2G3tHZyo0TDEmKAGoJI5gKGU2zmSAfmiRjqdXQKDzMyYmAGM8RHlPOYcF7tn2-a6e8VXmRkKSsoBVFGhFUfxjAAM6k6NXpm8wPCpnjpEOtgIotlBhEJAvMum4Rp4fH4AiMUEFQv1BogKHoIEdkAAaDEDD6dIx4uyfbrDGzJJjpPqMQa7Y6kqlYnHJUQkg4rJhAA)

You don't actually **need** to have the type alias, though, you could use `typeof eventHandlers` instead:

```typescript
type Events = "foo" | "bar";

type EventsPayload = { foo: string; bar: number };
type EventHandler<Event extends Events> = (args: EventsPayload[Event]) => void;

const eventHandlers: { [Event in Events]?: EventHandler<Event> } = {};
export function addEventHandler<Event extends Events>(
    name: Event,
    handler: typeof eventHandlers[Event]
) {
    eventHandlers[name] = handler;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAzlAvFARAMwPZ5ZQA+2ARgIYBOWA3ALABQToksCyKAChSADZ4KAEwxQA3lHx4AXFBTAqAS0QBzWlEpVZiAK4BbMhCpQAvg0ato8JMAASFREL5GAPNeRQIAD2BIhad1QAPlEACmoVFFlA7l4BYQBtQIBdAEoMELg8RSFzJgBjPER5Tw47BycjKPEoJLKoZXYbFGSAfmiy+0dnKjcykJNRMTMmbzA8KmBJHUR84EUiqGEhQK7K3sDPHz8AspQg0KYoY6hECj0IDpsAGiOTgAsKntlLPBxSmzWelDqbZKZ0mI7scIJ0nlUEmcLslRI9ukZzCYmEA)

Subjectively speaking, to me it's clearer if we have a type alias to work with.